# Detect if string matches format specifier string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, string-formatting

I'm trying to do the process of formatting a string in reverse, that is to match an existing string to a printf like string format specifier string.

I have an array of several strings, like so:

```
var strings = [
     "I have the number 5 and the word dog",
     "15 of your cows are belong to us"
];
```

I also have an array of format strings that correspond to these strings:

```
var formats = [
    "I have the number %i and the word %s",
    "%i of your %s are belong to us"
];
```

In my particular use case, I only need to match integers and single word strings.

```
function getFormatString(string) {
    //What I'm trying to accomplish
}

getFormatString(strings[0]); //returns formats[0];
getFormatString(strings[1]); //returns formats[1];
```

Building a regular expression for each format string seems to be the best idea I can think of, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I also want to extract the values of the string using the format string.

Comment: have you tried using substring? and What if the particular string doesn't match the amount of words in the format string?

Comment: The number of "words" should always match if the format is for the string - I'm relying on the %s strings to be single word strings only.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand what you're asking, but Underscore.js offers a printf style string formatting? You could use that maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your format strings to become regexes :

- replace `%i` by `(-?[\d]+)`
- replace `%s` by `(.*)`
- add start and end markers

This is the result :

```
var formats = [ 
    "^I have the number (-?[\d]+) and the word (.*)$", 
    "^(-?[\d]+) of your (.*) are belong to us$" 
];
```

In your function you loop over the format strings until one of them matches.

Comment: That seems to work perfectly! It even grabs the values properly when matching. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking the same thing as Lorenz, because it really is the only option. Here's a script that should do it for you.

You can also use this to convert your array. I even added the ability to escape percentages signs (if only js' regex supported lookbehinds, would be a much easier task).

```
var strings = [
     "I have the number 5 and the word dog",
     "15 of your cows are belong to us",
     "1 of these strings should fail, because strings is matched against a %i."
];

var formats = [
    "I have the number %i and the word %s",
    "%i of your %s are belong to us",
    "1 of these strings should fail, because %i is matched against a \\%i."
];

var formex = [];
for (i=0; i<formats.length; i++) {
    formex[i] =  "^" + formats[i].replace(/([^\w\s\\%])/g,"\\$1").replace(/(^|[^\\])%i/gi,"$1\(\\d+\)").replace(/(^|[^\\])%s/gi,"$1\([a-z]+\)").replace(/\\%/g,"%") + "$";
}

console.log(formex);

for (i=0; i<formats.length; i++) {
    console.log("Testing: <" + strings[i] + "> against <" + formex[i] + ">.");
    console.log(strings[i].match(formex[i]));
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65p15d77/5/)